# C preprocessor evaluate sin() of constant

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, trigonometry

Is there a way to convince the **C** preprocessor to evaluate a transcendental function of a constant at compile-time?

For example, replace `(int)256*sin(PI/4)` with `181`. This will help me keep magic numbers out of my code.

If it makes a difference, I'm using MSPGCC 4.5.3 and I have no `sin()` or `cos()` available at runtime.

Comment: *This will help me keep magic numbers out of my code* Uh... so in `(int)256*sin(PI/4)` you're saying `256` and `4` don't already exist in your code?

Comment: pi/4 and 256 are obvious to me at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your arguments are all within the range [-π/4,+π/4], you can use the same formula standard implementations of libm use to compute sin. It's correct up to the last place (at most 1ulp error) just like the IEEE standard requires:

```
static const double 
half =  5.00000000000000000000e-01, /* 0x3FE00000, 0x00000000 */
S1  = -1.66666666666666324348e-01, /* 0xBFC55555, 0x55555549 */
S2  =  8.33333333332248946124e-03, /* 0x3F811111, 0x1110F8A6 */
S3  = -1.98412698298579493134e-04, /* 0xBF2A01A0, 0x19C161D5 */
S4  =  2.75573137070700676789e-06, /* 0x3EC71DE3, 0x57B1FE7D */
S5  = -2.50507602534068634195e-08, /* 0xBE5AE5E6, 0x8A2B9CEB */
S6  =  1.58969099521155010221e-10; /* 0x3DE5D93A, 0x5ACFD57C */

double __kernel_sin(double x, double y, int iy)
{
    double z,r,v;
    int ix;
    ix = __HI(x)&0x7fffffff;    /* high word of x */
    if(ix<0x3e400000)           /* |x| < 2**-27 */
       {if((int)x==0) return x;}        /* generate inexact */
    z   =  x*x;
    v   =  z*x;
    r   =  S2+z*(S3+z*(S4+z*(S5+z*S6)));
    if(iy==0) return x+v*(S1+z*r);
    else      return x-((z*(half*y-v*r)-y)-v*S1);
}
```

Source: http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/k_sin.c

While not what I'd call pleasant, you definitely can convert that whole function into a macro that will evaluate to a (compile-time) floating point constant expression. (Ignore the bit hackery at the beginning that has nothing to do with the value, and as far as I know you should assume `iy` is 0.)

Comment: Regarding `iy`, you can assume it's 0. The only time it's nonzero is when the argument was obtained by range-reduction from an original argument outside the range -pi/4 to pi/4 (extra precision is needed then because reduction modulo 2pi cannot give an accurate result in just double precision). It doesn't apply as long as your arguments are in range, and even if they're not and you did your own range reduction, you probably won't care about a couple ulp of error.

Answer (score 4):

The C preprocessor can't provide sin() or cos().

For my applications, I use a perl script to create a separate .h file containing the needed precalculations.  There are probably sexier ways to do it, but this integrates into my workflow well enough.

Comment: good point. I sometimes do the similar trick by generating 'include' files (.i suffix to avoid confusion), using C as part of the build. It is comparable to using flex to generate a C source file. Good thinking, I +1 you!

Comment: The preprocessor is near turing complete so a sin and cos could be implemented in the preprocessor alone. You would just need to work around the lack of floating points.

Answer (score 4):

The preprocessor can only resolve macros, something quite different from performing a function. The closest solution I can think of to reduce your magic numbers is creating a header with the most used sins or co-sins values:

```
#define SIN_PI  (-1)
#define SIN_PI2 0
#define SIN_PI4 0.707106781186548
...
```

Then you can write:

```
256*SIN_PI2
```

And let the compiler optimization reduce it to a single constant.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is much more ambitious in the range of initialisation it will do. 
Is there any possibility of changing to a version of g++, does mspgcc include it?

Edit: After a bit of searching their website and email archives, AFAICT mspgcc does **not** support g++ :-(
That'd be such an easy fix.